# Random Number generator with skewness

Tags: java

I'm looking for a way to generate a random number with:

- A lower and upper boundary
- An average not in the middle of the specified range
- An adjustable standard deviation

In Java.

More specifically: I want to generate a long list of numbers with a minimum of 0, maximum of 40 and an average of +- 5, and i'd like to be able to adjust how far around the average the numbers are.

Comment: So? Is there a question here?

Comment: Yes? i'm asking if anyone knows how to do this? I've played around with Random, but this doesn't seem to do the job.

Comment: Good, you seems to have a complet requirement. But have you tried something ? We are not a free coding service.

Comment: Maybe something like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31754209/can-random-nextgaussian-sample-values-from-a-distribution-with-different-mean)?

Comment: In fairness to the OP, this is not easy to search, and is not particularly trivial either.

Comment: Why dont you write your own random depending on previous value + shift?

Comment: @Bathsheba where is guarantees, that he spent some time on research before posting this question?

Comment: Hey sorry guys but I've been looking for a solution for this for like 2 hours :(

Comment: @WimSchmitz: Methinks you'll need to set aside a good fortnight if your mathematics are rusty.

Comment: @Bathsheba I barely passed statistics last year, mabye that's the problem ;)

Answer (score 1):

Sadly statistics doesn't work like that.

1. You need to define the *distribution* that you want.
2. You then get the *quantile* function for that distribution.
3. You then draw a uniform number in [0, 1).
4. You apply the quantile function to (3).

The distribution of (4) will then have the properties that you want.