# Alter Z-Score of Outcomes Determined by Math.random()

Tags: javascript, math

I am generating binary outcomes using Math.random().

Using the string of outcomes, I am calculating the z-score and I was wondering if there was a way to determine the z-score that will result from using the Math.random() function.

This should not change the success rate, just how the outcomes are distributed.

I am wondering how I would even go about doing this.

Comment: maybe these help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/36481059/9638388 and then https://stackoverflow.com/a/31754210/9638388

Comment: Thanks, those gave me a good idea of which direction I should be going.